# Black screen when launching games, but not when stress testing

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver, amd-ryzen

I am building a new system, and I am still waiting on my GPU (RTX 3080) to arrive. I have found similar problems, but not as specific as mine.

The problem I have with this system is the following... Whenever I launch a game, I get a black screen (no signal from GPU), sometimes during the loading screen or after 15-20 seconds. I can still hear the sounds in the game, and after 10 seconds, the black screen has occurred. I can hear the notification sound of the windows, like new hardware being plugged in / detected. At this point, I have to restart my pc to regain the display.

After the restart, I can see the notification that the display drivers have crashed. I have tried stress testing the system with Aida64 Extreme, and it goes fine without freezing / crashing / black screens. I have also tried Memtest86, and it shows no errors/freezing even after 2-3 hours of running. I can leave YouTube on for hours, and it doesn't crash. I am waiting on my RTX 3080 to arrive, and until then, I am stuck with this old GPU. To make things even more complicated, the GPU works like a charm when I plug it in the old computer I have no crashes, nothing.

Things I have tried so far:

- Stress testing with Memtest86, Aida64 Extreme (All good)
- Launching different games (all result with black screen)
- Turning off XMP, Precision Boost Overdrive
- Removing one RAM stick, booting with one, switching slots, etc.
- Trying both PCI-express lanes.
- Trying 3 different power cables for the GPU.
- Reseating the GPU countless times to make sure the double lock is properly engaged
- Removing BIOS battery and clearing
- Clean install windows
- I tried different SSDs and windows versions.
- Tried cleaning drivers with DDU and installing older drivers
- I tried undervolting and downclocking the GPU.
- Tried changing the PCI-express Gen 2-3-4
- I tried with 1 monitor only and changed the HDMI / DP cable
- Tried F30 and F31q BIOS

I Q-Flashed the bios when I received the motherboard to prepare it for the CPU (Ryzen 5900x). Everything went great, and the bios version is F31o (AGESA Version 1.1.0.0).

My system:

MB: X570 Aorus Elite (F31o bios)
CPU: Ryzen 9 5900x
Ram: 2 x 16gb 3600Mhz G.Skill TridentZ RGB 16-19-19-39
GPU: Asus STRIX GTX 970 Direct CUII 4Gb
SSD: Kingston 240Gb (just for testing purposes)
PSU: Evga Supernova GA 850W Gold Plus
Cpu Cooling: Corsair iCue H100i RGB Pro XT
Monitor: 2 x Dell U2719D
Windows: Win10 Pro x64 (latest update)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I want to use the new system with my GTX 970 until the new GPU arrives. Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

EDIT:
DXDiag screenshots, and Event Viewer report of the driver crash.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/iELJuvr.png]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not using the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter driver.... I am using a proper Nvidia driver and when the crash occurs, this is the notification that pops after I restart the PC. GPU is fully functional on my old PC.

Comment: [This](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3633/~/opengl-%E2%80%9Ctdr-detected%E2%80%9D-meaning) indicates the workload being requested is exceeding the allowed limit.  I don't believe the limit can be increased.  So I go back to my first thought, how did you determine, this GPU was functional exactly?  This could be a power issue.  [**I would try to downclock the GPU slightly.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3puInnaG5ok).

Comment: Are you using a PCI-E riser cable?

Comment: As I stated I am using the same GPU in my old PC, and it works flawlessly. It plays games, launches 3D apps without any problem. I have tried downclocking it, still crashes the same. And no I am not using a PCI-E riser..

Comment: I suspect the PSU in that case

Comment: Hmmm, seems unlikely a brand new EVGA Supernova 850w to be faulty... In any case I don't have another one compatible for the new PC, so I guess I will have to take the whole PC somewhere to be tested.